Synchronise code generation for REST API vs GraphQL using Swagger/OpenAPI, GraphQL-Codegen
As the title says, I have a concern where my spring-boot service use both REST and GQL for API layer and I'm looking for a synchronised code-generation mechanism that aligns generated classes from both REST and GQL generators. E.g., I might use Swagger-Codegen/OpenAPI Generator to generate POJOs from REST API documentation and another plugin (i.e. GraphQL-Codegen) to generate POJOs from GQL schema separately.
The concern arises when the generated classes overlap and the codebase becomes clumsy and hard to maintain. I need a cleaner way to maintain the Codegen process with de-duplication of generated classes. Or any existing comparison tool for such generated classes would be helpful as well.
TIA
